# Proving that binary products exists

Tags: category-theory, monoid

I have to show that $\textbf{Mon}$ the category of monoids have all finite products. For this we require the existence of a terminal object (a nullary product) and the existence of all binary products. Now the monoid with only one element $1$ can play the role of the terminal object (correct?). But to show that all binary products exists I have to show that all product diagrams have the UMP (universal mapping property), that is having a binary product $M\times N$ with projections $\pi_1,\pi_2$ being $\pi_1:M\times N\to M$ (I guess taking $(m,n)\mapsto (m,1)$) and similar for $\pi_2$, then if we have two other maps into $M$ and $N$ from an object $T$ ($\tau_1:T\to M$ and $\tau_2:T\to N$) we will get a so called mediating morphism $\alpha :T\to M\times N$ which fullfills $\tau_1=\pi_1\circ \alpha$ and the same for $\tau_2$. And here I am stuck. Any hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, $\{1\}$ serves as terminal object (and also as initial object) in the category of monoids. For $\pi_1$ you should take $\langle m,n\rangle\mapsto m$ (not $\mapsto\langle m,1\rangle\notin M$). Morphism $\alpha$ can be prescribed by $t\mapsto\langle\tau_1(t),\tau_2(t)\rangle$.

Comment: ohh... true about $\pi_1$ sry. 
thank you, let me smelt this

Comment: One more question: where did we use here that we are considering $\mathbf{Mon}$? I mean I could do this in an arbitrary category, right? I mean the same construction for the mediating morphism.

Comment: First of all the arrows in **Mon** are functions and this fact has been used here. Secondly, of course you should check wether the projections and the prescribed $\alpha$ are indeed arrows in **Mon**. On the other hand: this is a construction that will indeed often work. Most categories have finite products, and I do not have counterexamples at hand.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: @drhab The category of fields and field homomorphisms is a counterexample.

Comment: @StefanPerko Ah, yes. There the arrows are injective, right? Then the (non-injective) projections will lack, I guess.